# SwiftUI List insets acting differently in Pro and Pro Max devices

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a simple List with a row with a background image and a text.

```
    List {
        Section {
            NavigationLink {
                Color.red
            } label: {
                Text("Background")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(height: 48)
            }
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
            .background {
                Image("Mist")
            }
        }
    }
```

Interestingly, SwiftUI renders this row differently in Pro and Pro Max devices.

**iPhone 15 Pro works as expected:**

[image]

**iPhone 15 Pro Max adds inset to Image and I cannot remove it**
[image]

I see the same behaviour for iPhone 14 Pro & Pro Max devices too.

Does anyone know why SwiftUI applies different insets in Pro and Pro Max devices and how can I make it stretch to full row?

Image in the example above:

[image: Background Image]

Thanks

Comment: You are not doing anything to scale the image to fill the space, so are you sure, it is wide enough to fill the larger display? Try adding ```.resizable()``` and ```.scaledToFill()``` to the ```Image```.

Comment: The image is large enough to fill every iPhone size. 

Applying `.resizable()` and `.scaledToFill()` to the `Image` makes it even worse by increasing the padding.

Comment: That sounds like the image itself includes a blank frame around the adges. Try checking that the image content actually reaches to the edges of the image.

Comment: No, it does not have any blank frame around the edges. I use it as a background image on another screen, and it works fine. Seems like a List issue rather than an image issue.

Comment: OK, please include the image in the question so that it can be used for reproducing the problem.

Comment: Added the image in the question 

Comment: Add a list style explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.listRowBackground` instead of `.background`. You might also like to use `.scaledToFill` so that it fits the space more exactly.

Like this:

```swift
List {
    Section {
        NavigationLink {
            Color.red
        } label: {
            Text("Background")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(height: 48)
        }
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
        .listRowBackground(
            Image("Mist")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Pleased to hear it, thanks for accepting the answer. The ```scaledToFill``` is actually important because the image you attached to the question is only 375 pixels wide -> not wide enough to fill the row on large phones without scaling.